# Parse array of string [] separated by comma to 2d array C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parsing

I have a large array of say length 3 in C# filled with strings:

The strings:

myArray[0,0] contains: "1,11,2,18,4"

myArray[0,1] contains: "2,21,12,138,14"

myArray[0,2] contains: "1,131,21,138,24"

I want to go through this array of strings (so 0,0 to 0,2. Or if I have a million, [0,0] to [0,999999]), split up the numbers by their commas, and generate basically this:

```
var a = new int [,] { {1 , 11, 2, 18, 4 }, {2, 21, 12, 138, 14}, {1, 131, 21, 138, 24 } };
```

Comment: `"1,11,2,18,4".Split(',').Select(n=>int.parse(n)).ToArray();` will give you the array.

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to convert one into an array doing this:

var test = Array.ConvertAll(myArray.Split(','), int.Parse);

I'm just not sure how to 'append' them into one 2D array if that makes sense. 
I need it to be the exact equivalent to 
var a = new int [,] { {1 , 11, 2, 18, 4 }, {2, 21, 12, 138, 14}, {1, 131, 21, 138, 24 } };
else my other of code won't work.

Comment: I had imagined I'd have to make the array in advance, then populate it. 
So I had tried 
double[,] TEST1 = new double[3, 5];
But I would have to individually fill in each 'position'. I just imagined there's some simple function to perform this from an array, without me having to make a loop to manually fill each position, for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not easily solved with LINQ, since the output must be a 2-dimensional array. Therefore I'm using the good old loops. I'm also using a one-dimensional string array as input. For the code to work, all lines must contain the same number of integers (given as `SubArrayLength` here):

```
const int SubArrayLength = 5;

string[] myArray = { "1,11,2,18,4", "2,21,12,138,14", "1,131,21,138,24" };

var a = new int[myArray.Length, SubArrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
    var numbers = myArray[i].Split(',');
    for (int j = 0; j < SubArrayLength; j++) {
        a[i, j] = Int32.Parse(numbers[j]);
    }
}
```

If it is not a problem for you to have a jagged array (i.e., an array of arrays) instead of multi-dimensional array, you can use this LINQ code:

```
string[] myArray = { "1,11,2,18,4", "2,21,12,138,14", "1,131,21,138,24" };

var a = myArray
    .Select(s => s.Split(',').Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

In this second example `a` is of type `int[][]` instead of `int[,]`. The lengths of the nested arrays can differ.

Answer (score -1):

For future people, I just coded it the long way.

```
int[,] TEST1 = new int[e, 30];
var test = (Array.ConvertAll(testOfIt.Split(','), int.Parse));

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
            {
                TEST1[i, j] = test[j];
            }
}
```